# Firebase database automatically generated cryptic node child object iteration

Tags: angular

I am not able to dig out the Employee object got nested in the automatically generated cryptic node in the firebase table.
Below is the screen shot of the FB table and the related codes.

[FB Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cpp8W.png)

**EmployeeService  Code:**

```js
export class EmployeeService {

  private employeeURL = "https://student-28bbd.firebaseio.com/employees.json";

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getEmployees(): Observable < Employee[] > {
    return this.http.get < Employee[] > (this.employeeURL, httpHeader)
  }

  saveEmployee(employee: Employee): Observable < Employee > {
    return this.http.post < Employee > (this.employeeURL, employee, httpHeader)
  }
}
```

**Component code:**

```js
export class EmployeeListComponent implements OnInit {

  employees: Employee[] = [];

  constructor(private employeeService: EmployeeService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getEmployees();
  }

  getEmployees() {
    this.employeeService.getEmployees()
      .subscribe(
        employee => this.employees = employee
      )
  }

  saveEmployee(id: number, name: string, age: number, designation: string, salary: number, phone: number, email: string) {
    this.employeeService.saveEmployee({
          id,
          name,
          age,
          designation,
          salary,
          phone,
          email
        }
        as Employee)
      .subscribe(
        items => this.employees.push(items)
      )
  }
}
```

**HTML template:**

```html
<div>
  <div style="text-align:right;">
    <label for="">ID: <input type="text" #empID></label><br>
    <label for="">Name: <input type="text" #empName></label><br>
    <label for="">Age: <input type="text" #empAge></label><br>
    <label for="">Designation: <input type="text" #empDesig></label><br>
    <label for="">Salary: <input type="text" #empSal></label><br>
    <label for="">Phone: <input type="text" #empPh></label><br>
    <label for="">Email: <input type="text" #empEmail></label><br>
    <button (click)="saveEmployee(empID.value, empName.value, empAge.value, empDesig.value, empSal.value, empPh.value, empEmail.value)"> Add Employee</button>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
<div>
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let employee of employees">
      {‌{ employee.name }} <span (click)="deleteEmployee(employee)">X</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Thank you so much in anticipation of your help.